# How to use purrr::pmap to plot multiple ggplot in nested.data.frame

Tags: r, ggplot2, purrr

I have some questions about purrr::pmap to make multiple plots of ggplot in nested.data.frame.

I can run below code without problem by using purrr::map2 and I can make multiplots(2 plots) in nested.data.frame.

As a example, I used the iris dataset in R.

```
library(tidyverse)

iris0 <- iris
iris0 <-
iris0 %>%  
group_by(Species) %>%  
nest() %>%  
mutate(gg1 = purrr::map(data, ~ ggplot(., aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width)) + geom_point())) %>%
mutate(gg2 = purrr::map(data, ~ ggplot(., aes(Sepal.Length, Petal.Width)) + geom_point())) %>%
mutate(g = purrr::map2(gg1, gg2, ~ gridExtra::grid.arrange(.x, .y)))
```

But, when I want to plot more than 2 plots, I can't solve using purrr::pmap like below code.

```
iris0 <-  
iris0 %>%  
group_by(Species) %>%  
nest() %>%  
mutate(gg1 = purrr::map(data, ~ ggplot(., aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width)) + geom_point())) %>%
mutate(gg2 = purrr::map(data, ~ ggplot(., aes(Sepal.Length, Petal.Width)) + geom_point())) %>%
mutate(gg3 = purrr::map(data, ~ ggplot(., aes(Sepal.Length, Petal.Length)) + geom_point())) %>%
mutate(g = purrr::pmap(gg1, gg2,gg3, ~ gridExtra::grid.arrange(.x, .y, .z)))

> Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : Index 1 is not a length 1 vector
```

Is there is a way of solving this problem in nested.data.frame ?
Please give me some advices or answers.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`purrr::pmap` takes (at least) two arguments:

```
 pmap(.l, .f, ...)
```

where

```
  .l: A list of lists. The length of '.l' determines the number of
      arguments that '.f' will be called with. List names will be
      used if present.
  .f: A function, formula, or atomic vector.
```

Further, `.x` and `.y` work well for only two arguments, but (in the same man page) it says `For more arguments, use '..1', '..2', '..3' etc`.

For readability (and a little efficiency), I'll combine all of the individual calls to `mutate` into one; you can keep them separate if needed (esp if there is more to the code than you show in this reduced example):

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)
library(ggplot2)
iris0 <- iris %>%  
  group_by(Species) %>%  
  nest() %>%  
  mutate(
    gg1 = purrr::map(data, ~ ggplot(., aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width)) + geom_point()),
    gg2 = purrr::map(data, ~ ggplot(., aes(Sepal.Length, Petal.Width)) + geom_point()),
    gg3 = purrr::map(data, ~ ggplot(., aes(Sepal.Length, Petal.Length)) + geom_point()),
    g = purrr::pmap(list(gg1, gg2, gg3), ~ gridExtra::grid.arrange(..1, ..2, ..3))
  )
```

Comment: Thank you for  quick answers !　  I can solve my problem ! I have overlooked purrr::pmap needs list of lists. Thanks.

Comment: If it solves your problem, please "accept" it by selecting the checkmark to the left of the answer.