# How to make plots over a list of variable while keeping their names in r

Tags: r, ggplot2, lapply

I'm try to make bar charts over a list of variables. I can get plots. But I want each plot has a title using its variable name, so that I can identify which variables are using in the plot. And the same thing for the legend.I tried the function as.character(), and as.name() to get their names. But they does no work. I don't know how to retrieve their variable names. The similar problems occurs in my second lappy function.My codes follow:

```
varlist1=c(name[11:40)
ev="aff"

lapply(varlist1, function(nm) 
{
     q1=ggplot(data,aes(fill=data[[as.name(nm)]],x=aff))
     q1+geom_bar(stat="count",position="dodge")+theme_bw()+
     ggtitle(as.character(data[[nm]]),"By Aff")
}) 

lapply(varlist1, function(nm) 
{
     table(data[[as.name(nm)]], data[[ev]])
 })
```

Thank you very much!!

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/a/49943976/786542

Comment: If you want to do it using the `purrr` package's `map` functions, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47482288/how-to-use-purrrpmap-to-plot-multiple-ggplot-in-nested-data-frame) might help

Comment: There are fancy ways to do this, but it's generally a better idea to reshape your data to long form (e.g. with `tidyr::gather`) and use [`facet_wrap`](http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/facet_wrap.html). Also, [data will help you get a good answer](http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/facet_wrap.html).

Comment: Thanks for the help. But I got error said :Error in typeof(x) : argument "varlist1" is missing, with no default. And my codes are `generate_plot2 <- function(registry, varlist1) {
  varlist1 <- rlang::sym(varlist1)
  
  ggplot(data = registry, aes(fill=!!varlist1, x=affiliation )) +
    geom_bar(stat="count",position="dodge")+theme_bw()+
    ggtitle(varlist1)
}
lapply(registry, generate_plot2)` @Tung

Comment: @TongZhang: please share the data you're using for plotting. See this guide to learn how https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example?rq=1